# Issue connecting pub/sub from PCF

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, pcf

I'm trying to connect google Pub/Sub from PCF environment(Spring boot app). The app is successfully loaded the credentials from credentials.json file and it printed Project ID.  but it is printing below error after started.

c.g.a.oauth2.ComputeEngineCredentials : Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
ERROR 13 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected the service InnerService [FAILED] to be RUNNING, but the service has FAILED] with root cause
java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.

Here is the code which I'm using and I'm invoking this method from a sample rest controller.

```
public static void subscribeAsyncExample(String projectId, String subscriptionId) {
ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName =
    ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId);
System.out.println("Processing messages...");
MessageReceiver receiver =
    (message, consumer) -> {
      System.out.println("Id : " + message.getMessageId());
      System.out.println("Data : " + message.getData().toStringUtf8());
      consumer.ack();
    };
Subscriber subscriber = null;
try {
  subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver).build();
  subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
  subscriber.awaitTerminated();
} finally {
  if (subscriber != null) {
    subscriber.stopAsync();
  }
}
```

}

pom.xml

Spring boot: 2.3.2.RELEASE
spring-cloud-gcp.version: 1.1.3.RELEASE

`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
</dependency>



<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`

Log:
The default project ID is *******
Default credentials provider for service account *****-client-account@*******.gserviceaccount.com
Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision]

Comment: Can you share you source code?

Comment: How do you know that the credentials are correctly loaded?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Attached the log statement, which printed valid details which I mentioned in the credentials.json

Comment: Where did you get this trace? Is it at your app startup?